# spring integration amqp listener transacted

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-amqp

What is difference between acknowledgeMode.AUTO and acknowledgeMode.MANUAL when is channelTransacted = true on message listener container?

I understand that when I want to use acknowledgeMode.MANUAL with channelTransacted=false, the listener must acknowledge message by calling Channel.basicAck(). Is it unnecessary use acknowledgeMode.MANUAL when listener container has channelTransacted = true? Because when I combine acknowledgeMode.MANUAL and channelTransacted=true with calling Channel.basicAck() I get exception.

```
@Bean(name = "amqpInboundEsignRequest")
public IntegrationFlow amqpInbound(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(
            Amqp.inboundAdapter(connectionFactory, EsignContstants.QUEUE)
                    .acknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.MANUAL)
                    .messageConverter(new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter())
                    .autoStartup(false)
                    .channelTransacted(true)
                    .transactionManager(transactionManager)
                    .txSize(1)
    )
            .enrichHeaders(s -> s.header(MessageHeaders.REPLY_CHANNEL, "basicAck.flow", true))
            .log("amqpInbound.start-process")
            .channel("insertAndStartProcess.input")
            .get();
}
```

exception

```
2018-02-19 09:57:27.478 ERROR 4664 --- [rContainer#0-45] o.s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationUtils  : TransactionSynchronization.afterCompletion threw exception

org.springframework.amqp.AmqpException: failed to commit RabbitMQ transaction
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.RabbitResourceHolder.commitAll(RabbitResourceHolder.java:168) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils$RabbitResourceSynchronization.afterCompletion(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:264) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils.invokeAfterCompletion(TransactionSynchronizationUtils.java:168) ~[spring-tx-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.invokeAfterCompletion(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:1002) [spring-tx-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.triggerAfterCompletion(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:977) [spring-tx-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:806) [spring-tx-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730) [spring-tx-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:150) [spring-tx-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1198) [spring-rabbit-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1600(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:102) [spring-rabbit-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1470) [spring-rabbit-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_131]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: null
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:105) ~[amqp-client-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:101) ~[amqp-client-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:123) ~[amqp-client-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.txCommit(ChannelN.java:1318) ~[amqp-client-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.txCommit(ChannelN.java:50) ~[amqp-client-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor151.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$CachedChannelInvocationHandler.invoke(CachingConnectionFactory.java:980) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy191.txCommit(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.RabbitResourceHolder.commitAll(RabbitResourceHolder.java:164) ~[spring-rabbit-1.7.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 11 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - unknown delivery tag 1, class-id=60, method-id=80)
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.ValueOrException.getValue(ValueOrException.java:66) ~[amqp-client-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:32) ~[amqp-client-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:366) ~[amqp-client-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.privateRpc(AMQChannel.java:229) ~[amqp-client-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:117) ~[amqp-client-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - unknown delivery tag 1, class-id=60, method-id=80)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.asyncShutdown(ChannelN.java:505) ~[amqp-client-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.processAsync(ChannelN.java:336) ~[amqp-client-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleCompleteInboundCommand(AMQChannel.java:143) ~[amqp-client-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleFrame(AMQChannel.java:90) ~[amqp-client-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.readFrame(AMQConnection.java:634) ~[amqp-client-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.access$300(AMQConnection.java:47) ~[amqp-client-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:572) ~[amqp-client-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
    ... 1 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using transactions shouldn't make any difference; that error implies the channel was closed for some reason between when you received the message and sent the `basicAck`, with transactions we won't detect it until the transaction commits.

We recently [added a fix to detect the channel was closed](https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP-793) and reject the `basicAck` in that case.

The fix is in 2.0.2.RELEASE.